# How to solve an error while converting timestamp to time?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a database table name "c_pay_daily_attend as da" in postgresql like:

| Name | da.outime6 |
| --- | --- |
| Zakir | 2018-09-06 15:00:00 |

I want just time like this:

| Name | da.outime6 |
| --- | --- |
| Zakir | 15:00:00 |

I am using

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(da.outime6, 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME
```

but it is getting the following error

> ```
> ERROR:  function to_timestamp(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
> LINE 1: select TO_TIMESTAMP(da.intime6, 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME ee,bp.c_...
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for two years now. You should really plan an upgrade to Version 10 or 11 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cast() function

```
SELECT Cast(da.outime6 :: timestamp AS TIME) 
FROM   c_pay_daily_attend AS da
```

Comment: @ZakirHossain: `da.outime6::timestamp` is completely useless if `outime6` is already defined as `timestamp`

Answer (score 2):

use time conversion below way

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time
```

[demo in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=33564f706d55e0ab8338aba3325e37c5)

Answer (score 1):

`outime6` seems to be already a timestamp, so there is no need to convert it first.

Just cast it to a `time` value:

```
da.outime6::time
```

Comment: @ZakirHossain: What do you mean with "more dynamic"? What data type **is** that column?